# Changing multiple rows to columns (Pivotable) in a table from mysql

Tags: mysql

Can you help me?i wanna get more information and changes my Query

```
select * from(
        select count(*) as 'To_Recharge' from table_in where created_on like '%2020-02%') as A
        cross join(
        select count(*) as 'Recharge_u' from table_in where created_on like '%2020-02%) as B
        cross join(
        select count(*) as 'Recharge_S' table_in where created_on like '%2020-02% and c_by=1 )as C
        cross join(
        select count(*) as 'O_recharge' table_in where created_on like '%2020-02%)as d);
```

The result Query is :

> To_Recharge | Recharge_u  | Recharge_S   | O_recharge
>
> ---
>
> ```
>   500      |    250   |   250     | 0
> ```
>
> ---

**Can I change to(transpose):**

```
----------------------
| To_Recharge | 500  |
----------------------
| Recharge_U | 250   |
----------------------
| Recharge_S | 250   |
----------------------
| O_recharge | 0     |
----------------------
```

**Thanks too much for your help and efforts. **

Comment: I don't believe that this query would produce anything other than a syntax error. But I don't answer questions with 'wanna' in them, so either way, you're unlikely to get more from me.

Comment: Use unions instead of joins.